# Почему не работает кириллица в шрифте?

Tags: css, шрифты

Скачал шрифт формата TTF [отсюда](http://homeprofitmasters.com/IFHnc/style3.css). Конвертирюу с помощью [этого](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) конвертора в другие форматы. Выбираю английские и кирилические символы, но почему-то кириллица не работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: он убирает кириллицу. Я пока вызода не нашел, разве что подключать ttf без конвертации. Но в IE не работает

Comment: В том то и дело, что в IE не работает. А с чего вы взяли, что он кирилицу отключает? Я просто несколько дней назад другие шрифты конвертировал, всё работало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@font-face Generator** - сервис хороший, но действительно с кириллицей проблемы. Сам сталкивался неоднократно. Выручал другой - **[Font2Web](http://www.font2web.com/)**. Без каких-то дополнительных возможностей, но справляется с задачей хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто включить настроку поддержки кириллицы в fontsquirrel, а font2web кириллицу не переобразует вообще.

Comment: Как раз-таки с кириллицей на этом сервисе все в порядке

Comment: Вчера переводил через него, otf шрифты с кириллицей, в итоге eot и svg перегнались только англоязычные символы, а кириллица осталось без оформления.

Comment: eot перегнались через Font2web нормально с кириллицей (просто там есть баг, нужно каждое начертание шрифта делать отдельным шрифтом, иначе ие не понимает), но svg без кириллицы.